# How to get cookies in CEF + MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm integrating CEF with my MFC application (I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1105945/Embedding-a-Chromium-browser-in-an-MFC-application)) and i don't know how to get the request cookies, i'm trying in the *OnBeforeBrowse* method but still no success i also tried in the *OnResourceResponse* but i only manage to get some cookies inside the response.

A couple beginner questions: What the GetFirstPartyForCookies method does? i read the documentation and still didn't understood.
Was i supose to use the CefCookieManager? i thought i should use the VisitAllCookies method but the visitor parameter can't be empty it gives me an Assertion, i'm trying:

```
CefRefPtr<CefCookieManager> manager = CefCookieManager::GetGlobalManager(NULL);
CefRefPtr<CefCookieVisitor> visitor;

manager->VisitAllCookies(visitor);
```

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this answer on the  [CEF forum](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1437).

To retrieve the cookie i must create my own class derived from CefCookieVisitor and then call VisitAllCookies

```
CefRequestHandler::ReturnValue ClientHandler::OnBeforeResourceLoad(CefRefPtr< CefBrowser > browser,
    CefRefPtr< CefFrame > frame,
    CefRefPtr< CefRequest > request,
    CefRefPtr< CefRequestCallback > callback)
{
    auto strURL = request->GetURL();

    CefRefPtr<CefCookieManager> manager = CefCookieManager::GetGlobalManager(NULL);
    CefRefPtr<MyCookieVisitor> visitor = new MyCookieVisitor();
    manager->VisitAllCookies(visitor);

    return RV_CONTINUE;
}
```